# Search for an array of values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an index in elasticsearch where the body contains an array of a field with an array of values. For example:

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
    {
        "_index": "families",
        "_type": "family",
        "_id": "o8qxd2EB9CizMt-k15mv",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "names": [
            "Jefferson Erickson",
            "Bailee Miller",
            "Ahmed Bray"
        ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "families",
        "_type": "family",
        "_id": "osqxd2EB9CizMt-kfZlJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "names": [
            "Nia Walsh",
            "Jefferson Erickson",
            "Darryl Stark"
        ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "families",
        "_type": "family",
        "_id": "pMrEd2EB9CizMt-kq5m-",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
        "names": [
            "lia shelton",
            "joanna shaffer",
            "mathias little"
        ]
        }
    }
    ]
}
}
```

Now I need a search query in which I can search for documents from an array of values, something like this:

```
GET /families/_search
{
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
    "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
        "should" : [
            {"match_phrase" : {"names" : ["ahmed bray", "nia walsh"]}}
        ]
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

And it should return the 2 documents that contain these names like this:

```
{
"took": 0,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [
    {
        "_index": "families",
        "_type": "family",
        "_id": "o8qxd2EB9CizMt-k15mv",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
        "names": [
            "Jefferson Erickson",
            "Bailee Miller",
            "Ahmed Bray"
        ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_index": "families",
        "_type": "family",
        "_id": "osqxd2EB9CizMt-kfZlJ",
        "_score": 0,
        "_source": {
        "names": [
            "Nia Walsh",
            "Jefferson Erickson",
            "Darryl Stark"
        ]
        }
    }
    ]
}
}
```

How do i make a query like this? I tried using the "terms" keyword but "terms" only allows me to search from an array on single words like this:
{"terms" : {"names" : ["bray", "nia"]}}

But I need to look using the full names like this:
{"names" : ["ahmed bray", "nia walsh"]}}

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-multi-word.html#match-improving-precision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" you have is connected with the behavior how Elasticsearch treats text fields. By default each text field is tokenized with [Standard Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) which as you can see in the documentation splits text on words.

One option to achieve this is to improve default settings and mappings. All you need to do is to add [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) (`entire-phrase` in our case) which will be analyzed in a different way and search by it.

First create index with below settings/mappings:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "case_and_accent_insensitive": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "family": {
      "properties": {
        "names": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "entire-phrase": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "case_and_accent_insensitive"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then you can search what you expected by:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "names.entire-phrase": [
        "ahmed bray",
        "nia walsh"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You have to be warned that this search will find you any result only by first or last name. Only match for entire phrase. If you want to achieve both at once you have to search by both fields `names` and `names.entire-phrase`.